# VPN DNS fails for external hosts

Tags: networking, dns, vpn

I have a VPN provided by my employer.I have configured it as below.

When connected to the VPN I can access internal hosts but not external hosts. I can access external hosts via IP.
When connected to VPN `nslookup www.google.com` does not resolve however `nslookup www.google.com xxx.xxx.109.1` does connect (where the DNS server specified is the one listed in my VPN IPv4 settings tab).

Interestingly when connecting to the VPN using my phone as a mobile hotspot instead of connecting via my router the VPN and DNS works fine! This makes me thing it's something to do with my router (Virgin Media Hub 3.0 f/w 9.1.116V h/w 10)

Sorry I've had to obfuscate some of the details, hopefully it still provides enough information.
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This proved to be an issue with the Hub 3 router. I changed the router to use Modem mode then added a secondary router with VPN Passthrough enabled and it connected without any issue.